# Why does sending take so long? Does it depend only on POW or also on something else?

Tags: transaction, pow

If I do a transaction with my 2.6GHz laptop it last quite a long time in the status "sending" (1-3minutes). I know that it is because of the power of work that has to be done. But is the time always the same with the same operation system, or does it depend on something else?

Comment: ok I changed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time of PoW depends on

- The number of transactions your bundle contains (so if you are sending to multiple recipients or are using multisig addresses, more transactions need to be signed)
- The **Min Weight Magnitude** configured in your settings - it should be 14 (or you will waste time doing more PoW than needed)
- Whether or not you can use your GPU to do the POW (GPU is usually faster than CPU). This depends on your OS and/or your graphics drivers.

Comment: There is also a random factor in that the PoW just takes an unknown amount of tries. Sometimes your computer just guesses correct on the first try.

Comment: @user630: Very good point, PoW is probabilistic.